# Changing Deployment Url for Webpart in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, debugging

I am trying to debug a webpart in SharePoint 2007 using Visual Studio 2008.  When I click debug, it deploys the solution to http://localhost:8080. The url I want to deploy to is on a different port.  How do I debug against a different url?  In VS 2010 you can just change the deployment target url in the properties window.

UPDATE:

You can change the deployment port by changing "Start browser with URL" in the Debug tab of the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do the following:

- deploy wsp
- manually attach your debugger to the w3wp.exe process using "debug -> attach to process".